# MYSQL - Whitespace issue Group By

Tags: mysql, group-by, union, trim

I am performing `UNION` while getting the same type of information (*company_name*, *vat*, and *email*) from two different tables (*adv* and *pub*). The SQL query is below:

```
SELECT TRIM(UPPER(company_name)), vat, company_owner_email FROM (
    (SELECT company_name, vat, admin.email as company_owner_email FROM pub
        LEFT JOIN admin ON pub.manager = admin.id
        WHERE company_name > '')
        UNION
    (SELECT company_name, vat, admin.email as company_owner_email FROM adv
        LEFT JOIN admin ON adv.manager = admin.id
        WHERE company_name > '')
    ) company
GROUP BY company_name
ORDER BY company_name;
```

However, when I run this query, I am getting some rows with the same *company_name* and when I try to copy them in order to understand why they are not filtered, I am facing the following result.

- **'1DNAF SARL', '123456', NULL**
- **'1DNAF SARL         ', '', NULL**

  Even if I am using `TRIM()` function, it somehow doesn't work and as a result, `GROUP BY` doesn't consider these records identical and doesn't eliminate one of them. How should I solve this issue?

By the way, when I have tried to TRIM() the company_name field separately, it worked in both but to join the results doesn't work properly.

Comment: *"`GROUP BY` doesn't consider these records identical and doesn't eliminate one of them"* -- the purpose of `GROUP BY` is not to eliminate duplicates, `DISTINCT` does this. Your query is not valid SQL. In a `GROUP BY` query, the expressions in the `SELECT` clauses must be one of: 1. also present in the `GROUP BY` clause; 2. [aggregate (`GROUP BY`) functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html); 3. functionally dependent on one of the columns present in the `GROUP BY` clause. Read more: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to normalize the company name different ways in SELECT (how it will be displayed) and GROUP (how it will be grouped):

Consider that there might be cases with 2 spaces in the middle or TAB SPACE TAB in the end of the string. So I'd rather use replace instead of TRIM().

```
SELECT UPPER(company_name), vat, company_owner_email FROM (
    (SELECT company_name, vat, admin.email as company_owner_email FROM pub
        LEFT JOIN admin ON pub.manager = admin.id
        WHERE company_name > '')
        UNION
    (SELECT company_name, vat, admin.email as company_owner_email FROM adv
        LEFT JOIN admin ON adv.manager = admin.id
        WHERE company_name > '')
    ) company
GROUP BY replace(replace(replace(replace(company_name,'\t',''), ' ', ''), '.', ''), ',','')
ORDER BY company_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Group by TRIM(UPPER(company_name))`

Answer (score 2):

It's because to TRIM and UPPER are applied after grouping.
Try to move to functions to a lower level:

```
SELECT company_name, vat, company_owner_email FROM (
    (SELECT TRIM(UPPER(company_name)) as company_name, vat, admin.email as company_owner_email FROM pub
        LEFT JOIN admin ON pub.manager = admin.id
        WHERE company_name > '')
        UNION
    (SELECT TRIM(UPPER(company_name)) as company_name, vat, admin.email as company_owner_email FROM adv
        LEFT JOIN admin ON adv.manager = admin.id
        WHERE company_name > '')
    ) company
GROUP BY company_name
ORDER BY company_name;
```

Be careful with the results though. If you have different vat values in the two tables MySQL doesn't throw an error! It will just give you one or the other.

Comment: Unfortunately, the result is still the same. Actually, It was the first approach I have tried...

Comment: Looks like your problem wasn't the whitespace, but a \t (tab). :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT TRIM(CHAR(9) FROM TRIM(UPPER(company_name))) as cpm, vat, company_owner_email FROM (
(SELECT company_name, vat, admin.email as company_owner_email FROM pub
    LEFT JOIN admin ON pub.manager = admin.id
    WHERE company_name > '')
    UNION
(SELECT company_name, vat, admin.email as company_owner_email FROM adv
    LEFT JOIN admin ON adv.manager = admin.id
    WHERE company_name > '')
) company
GROUP BY TRIM(CHAR(9) FROM TRIM(UPPER(company_name)))
ORDER BY cpm;
```

This would trim out tabs after trimming out spaces. Most likely you have tabs in the columns along with whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TRIM(UPPER(company_name)), vat, company_owner_email FROM (
    (SELECT company_name, vat, admin.email as company_owner_email FROM pub
        LEFT JOIN admin ON pub.manager = admin.id
        WHERE company_name > '')
        UNION
    (SELECT company_name, vat, admin.email as company_owner_email FROM adv
        LEFT JOIN admin ON adv.manager = admin.id
        WHERE company_name > '')
    ) company
GROUP BY UPPER(replace(company_name,' ',''))
ORDER BY company_name;
```

I had tried below query.

**`select replace('1DNAF SARL         ',' ','') ='1DNAFSARL';`**

And it's returning **`1`**. This means it's considering both record as same.

Try above query.

Comment: It eliminated some of the records but unfortunately the sample records which I gave still remain..

Comment: @KaanBurakSener for sample data i had tried..It's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TRIM(UPPER(company_name)), vat, company_owner_email FROM (
    (SELECT company_name, vat, admin.email as company_owner_email FROM pub
        LEFT JOIN admin ON pub.manager = admin.id
        WHERE company_name > '')
        UNION
    (SELECT company_name, vat, admin.email as company_owner_email FROM adv
        LEFT JOIN admin ON adv.manager = admin.id
        WHERE company_name > '')
    ) company
GROUP BY TRIM(UPPER(company_name))
ORDER BY TRIM(UPPER(company_name));
```